# Formatting an eMMC to SD format

Tags: memory, sd-card, flash-memory, data-partitioning, fat32

I've been working with a Micron BGA eMMC chip and prototyping a communication scheme with the eMMC chip inside an adapter board that connects to the GPIO pins of a TI microcontroller.

I've essentially created a communication scheme written in C code to walk through the initial handshake and initialization steps to get the eMMC to a Data Write/Read stage where I can write some small amounts of bytes to a part of the sector memory and read back the pattern I've written.

My next task is to format the eMMC into a partition format such as a FAT32 format, which is common among SD cards.

- Does anyone know of any useful software or methods I could use to achieve this?
- Or I've seen it's possible to format the eMMC using a Linux setup as well, but have little experience when it comes to Linux.

Any insight from anyone with past experience on the topic would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

1. If your system runs Linux that is the best option.
   It is easy to format an eMMC using linux.

   ```
   # mkfs -t fat32 /dev/mmcblk1
   ```

   Is your TI microcontroller running Linux? If not, it might be diffiult connecting your BGA eMMC chip to a Linux system to format it.
2. Your second best option is to use a library that already supports it. Maybe something like (http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/00index_e.html) or (https://github.com/ryansturmer/thinfat32). There are several  options I have not used any of them. To use these layers, you have to fulfill the lower level api.